# woocommerce order-pay page redirect back to checkout

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming, woocommerce-checkout-fields

I have a problem with woocommerce checkout page.
when user field all items in the checkout form and submit form to go for payment it redirects to current page.

also when I check in network xhr requests I see that it successfully done

`{"result":"success","redirect":"https:\/\/tajhizman.ir\/checkout\/order-pay\/11395\/?key=wc_order_LsPv0uxqfXJOW","order_id":11395}`

I have copied url passed in 'redirect' and opened in new tab its go back to checkout page.

`https://tajhizman.ir/checkout/order-pay/11395/?key=wc_order_LsPv0uxqfXJOW` goes back to `https://tajhizman.ir/checkout/` page.

is there any way to fix it?